# What would be a correct C++ style for function loading file contents?

Tags: c++, stream

```
bool loadFileContents(const std::string& fileName, std::string &out) {
    bool res = false;
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "r");
    char buf[128] = { 0 };
    if (file) {
        while (fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), file))
            out += std::string(buf);
        res = true;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return res;
}
```

The rationale behind using `std::string` for the `out` parameter is that it handles the buffer underneath. However, I feel like it's a move from C-style, but not quite a C++ one.

Should I consider using some kind of stream for the `out` param?

Comment: [Here's the same SO question, which also has an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20980801/what-would-be-a-correct-c-style-for-function-loading-file-contents).

Comment: This was the result of a bad migration, so please do not vote to close or migrate.

Comment: Here is a question about copying a file. But the same rules apply. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10195343/14065

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some of the C-style features of your code:

- `FILE`
- `fopen`
- `char buf [128]`
- `fclose`

I personally liked the answer that was given in @Jamal's link.

```
std::ifstream fin(fileName);
std::ostringstream oss;

oss << fin.rdbuf();
out = oss.str();
```

The only problem with this is that it doesn't work well with binary files.
You could make `out` be a `std::vector <char>` instead.

```
std::vector <char> loadFileContents (const std::string &filename)
{
    std::ifstream ifile ;
    ifile.exceptions (std::ifstream::badbit | std::ifstream::failbit) ;

    std::vector <char> vecBuffer ;
    typedef std::vector <char>::size_type size_type ;

    try {
        ifile.open (filename) ;
        ifile.seekg (0, ifile.end) ;
        size_type size = static_cast <size_type> (ifile.tellg ()) ;
        ifile.seekg (0, ifile.beg) ;
        vecBuffer.resize (size) ;
        ifile.read (&vecBuffer [0], size) ;
    }

    catch (std::ios_base::failure &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what () << std::endl ;
    }

    return vecBuffer ;
}
```

[NRVO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) allows us not to worry about returning the `std::vector <char>` by value.

If you have access to C++11, then you could do:

```
std::vector <char> loadFileContents (const std::string &filename)
{
    std::ifstream ifile ;
    ifile.exceptions (std::ifstream::badbit | std::ifstream::failbit) ;

    std::vector <char> vecBuffer ;

    try {
        ifile.open (filename) ;
        std::istreambuf_iterator <char> iter (ifile) ;
        std::istreambuf_iterator <char> eos ;
        vecBuffer = std::move (std::vector <char> (iter, eos)) ;    
    }

    catch (std::ios_base::failure &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what () << std::endl ;
    }

    return vecBuffer ;
}
```

If you want to enter template territory, then you could try this:

```
template <typename Container>
Container loadFileContents (const std::string &filename)
{
    std::ifstream ifile ;
    ifile.exceptions (std::ifstream::badbit | std::ifstream::failbit) ;

    try {
        ifile.open (filename) ;
        std::istreambuf_iterator <char> iter (ifile) ;
        std::istreambuf_iterator <char> eos ;
        return Container (iter, eos) ;  
    }

    catch (std::ios_base::failure &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what () << std::endl ;
    }

    return Container () ;
}
```

Then in your main, you could do:

```
int main (void)
{
    std::string strData = loadFileContents <std::string> (FILENAME) ;
    std::vector <char> vecData = loadFileContents <std::vector <char> > (FILENAME) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

If we choose to not return the `Container`, then we could do:

```
template <typename Container>
void loadFileContents (const std::string &filename, Container &container)
{
    std::ifstream ifile ;
    ifile.exceptions (std::ifstream::badbit | std::ifstream::failbit) ;

    try {
        ifile.open (filename) ;
        std::istreambuf_iterator <char> iter (ifile) ;
        std::istreambuf_iterator <char> eos ;
        container = Container (iter, eos) ; 
    }

    catch (std::ios_base::failure &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what () << std::endl ;
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    std::string strData ;
    std::vector <char> vecData ;

    loadFileContents (FILENAME, strData) ;
    loadFileContents (FILENAME, vecData) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

The benefit of this one is that we wouldn't have to supply template arguments in `main`.